# Spacyr does not initialize to run NER

Tags: r, quanteda

I try to run this example.

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1, 2), 
                 text = c("My best friend John works at Google.", "However he
                          would like to work at Amazon as he likes to use
                          Python and stay in Canada."), 
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library("spacyr")
library("dplyr")

# -- need to do these before the next function will work:
# spacy_install()
# spacy_download_langmodel(model = "en_core_web_lg")

spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_lg")
#> Found 'spacy_condaenv'. spacyr will use this environment
#> successfully initialized (spaCy Version: 2.0.10, language model: en_core_web_lg)
#> (python options: type = "condaenv", value = "spacy_condaenv")

txt <- df$text
names(txt) <- df$id

spacy_parse(txt, lemma = FALSE, entity = TRUE) %>%
  entity_extract() %>%
  group_by(doc_id) %>%
  summarize(ner_words = paste(entity, collapse = ", "))
```

However when I try this I receive the following error:

```
spacy_initialize(model = "en_core_web_lg")

Finding a python executable with spaCy installed... Error in
set_spacy_python_option(python_executable, virtualenv, condaenv,  :   
spaCy or language model en_core_web_lg is not installed in any of
python executables.

spacy_initialize()

Finding a python executable with spaCy installed... Error in
set_spacy_python_option(python_executable, virtualenv, condaenv,  :   
spaCy or language model en is not installed in any of python
executables.
```

I installed `spacyr` from here

```
devtools::install_github("kbenoit/spacyr", build_vignettes = FALSE)
```

Is there any alternative way to make NER recognization?

Comment: Have you tried `spacy_download_langmodel("en_core_web_lg")` ?

Comment: You need to install `spacy` and language models before runnings NLP. I what you need is NER in English, the smallest model will be sufficient. 

```spacy_isntall()
```

Then

```spacy_initialize("en_web_core_sm")
```

If your system is running windows you may have to (Mini|Ana)conda separately.